# How to enforce the contract between a controller and a view in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, model-view-controller, web-applications

I'm building a PHP webapp and I'm following the MVC pattern as much as I can. So I have a controller file and a view file for each page or element in the page. The model is the database itself.

For example, on my index.php page I do all the business logic beforehand and then I output the view which is expecting a specific set of variables:

> index.php

```
<?php
// all the business logic here
$h = "hello";
$w = "world";

// setting up the variables that the view is expecting
$title = $h." ".$w;

// output the view
require("index.view.php");
?>
```

> index.view.php

```
    <div>
       <h1>
          <?php echo title; ?>
       </h1>
    </div>
```

So now my question is, I can easily figure out the exact number and the names of all the variables that the view file is expecting (in this case just one, the `title`). However, for very large and complex view this can became more and more difficult, very tedious and prone to name clashing with other views.

How can easily enforce this interface between the controller and the view and make it clear (from the controller) which variables the view needs? Using objects instead of a plain set of varibles? Using a function which echoes the view and take as parameters the needed variables? Or what?

Comment: This was nothing to do with MVC. What you have there is a basic plain-php templating. http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html ... that is **not MVC**.

Comment: I think it's very closely related to proper MVCing, please elaborate your statement or (better yet) provide some answer to the problem :-)

Comment: Read the provided link. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, given it is a php templating problem and not an MVC one, do you have any suggestion on how to do it properly?

Comment: Create a controller class and each controller extends that class. Create a view class and pass data array or object to view loading method

Comment: Ya know, in MVC, the controller should not be passing anything to the view. Controller's only responsibility is to alter the state of model layer. And then view inquires from model layer about its current state and populates the templates with the gathered data.

Comment: @charlietfl ok. And what if the view encapsulates other views? Like a page (parent view) which displays many repeated panels (child views).

Comment: There are numerous frameworks you could use and not have to re-invent the wheel. As for last question one view could also implement other views

Comment: @charlietfl yes I know, like codeigniter or cakePHP. Anyway I just want the theory behind it. So if you say that a view can also implement other views, does it mean that the parent view has got at least some sort of business logic into it just before outputting the child views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In homemade frameworks there are usually a class for View, where you can do these kinds of operations.

Something like:

```
class View 
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = array();
    }

    public function addParam($name, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function getParam($name)
    {
        return $this->data[$name];
    }
}
```

And you can have an object of this class in your view, instead of all the variables.

Or you can export this array with `extract` and make it visible in your view.

But, you'll have to know wich variables your view need, so you can provide them.

Comment: That's not a view: http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

Comment: @tereško PHP Templating and View in MVC is not the same. View is responsible for generating new output to the user based on changes in the model and getting user actions to controller. How it will be implemented doesn't matter. It can be a separate class or just a template. So the author of this answer is correct, if he posted just a part of whole class

Comment: @Clickbeetle what he describes there is **templating**. Which kinda makes him **not correct**. Normally a templating engine is just one of View's dependencies.

Comment: @tereško As Clickbeetle said, this is not the hole solution. It's just the part which the question was related to. What he wanted to know is how to pass variables to his visualization part of the program. Nothing more. 

;-)

Answer (score 0):

A popular solution from statically typed languages but that could be applied here is to create a special kind of model, basically as class, that contains all the data your specific view needs. This is refered to as a viewmodel.

Comment: "ViewModel" is something that replaces controller in MVVM architecture (best suited for codebases where you either have no control over UI layer of the model layer. I think what you actually meant is this thing: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html .... which seems way above OP's pay-grade.

Answer (score 0):

I will not discuss whether your design is MVC or not. Our ultimate purpose is "separation of concerns", not following a name of a pattern, especially a pattern with many variants like MVC.

Basically, your question is: what is the discipline so that the `Controller` would not forget setting a parameter to the `View`. There are some disciplines for this.

## Documentation

In the beginning of your `View` (file `index.view.php`) you can write some documentation here so that every `Controller` should read and know which parameters need to be passed.

I know, some of you may hate documentation. If documentation does not work for you,

## Using APIs with OOP

Just make your `View` become a class with methods for setting your parameters, and move the HTML stuff to another file so-called "template":

```
// file index.view.class.php
class View {
    private $title;
    private $foo;
    private $bar;

    public function setTitle($title) { $this->title = $title; }
    public function setFoo($foo) { $this->foo = $foo; }
    public function setBar($bar) { $this->bar = $bar; }

    public function show() {
        require("index.view.template.php");
    }
}

// file index.view.template.php
<div>
   <h1>
      <?php echo $this->title; ?>
      <?php echo $this->foo; ?>
      <?php echo $this->bar; ?>
   </h1>
</div>
```

This approach is a bit better than documentation because when you use a class you must know its public APIs. But when the list of those APIs is too long and you're asleep, chance is that you still forget setting one or several parameters. OK, everybody can make mistake. However, in this case, you found the mistake only when seeing the view on your web browser.

## Unit testing

Writing unit test for your `Controller` forces you to re-consider its requirement again, in a different context. Here, the requirement of the `Controller` is that all the methods `setTitle()`, `setFoo()`, `setBar()` of the `View` must be called. To do this verification, you can create a `mock` (`spy`, to be exact) object of your `View` and inject it into your `Controller`. After the execution of the `Controller`, you can check the state of the `mock` to see whether all the methods are called. Clearly, when you do the same thing twice in two different ways, the probability of mistakes can be reduced.

Of course, this discipline takes time and effort, but as we know, unit testing offers more benefits rather than verification. So, it's worth to apply.